# Enumerating over several cells in MySQL DB using PHP

Tags: php, mysql

**Problem:** I have several rows of results, for a single survey. Each survey can have any number of rows in the "Results" Table. There's a column called key_value. It's either 0 or -1. What is the fastest way in PHP to enumerate over several rows in a MySQL database, access each object, and flag a Boolean in PHP to tell me whether or not this particular survey has any rows with a key_value of 0?

something like this, except not brute forcing it...

```
for (i = 0; i < mysqlrows.length; i++){
    if (mysqlrow.key_value == 0)
        flag = true;
     else
        flag = false;
}
```

Comment: why you can't just retrieve rows subset and check whether `key_value` is 0 or -1 for each row? *I don't think I understand the question*

Comment: @Nemoden I guess that could be a viable solution, and I'm sort of asking how to do that. If you could provide an answer which includes what you say above, then I think that would answer my question and it would solve my problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To operate on all matching (key_value = 0) Results:

```
$query = <<<EOD
    SELECT result_id
    FROM Results
    WHERE key_value = 0
EOD;

$pdo = new PDO(....);
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($query);
if ($stmt->execute()) {
    while ($result = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        $result_id = $result['result_id'];
        //do something with this result?
    }
}
```

But if you only wanted the *number* of Results with key_value = 0, use some SQL like:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as num_with_zero FROM Results WHERE key_value = 0
```

Comment: PDO documentation (for connection string): http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.connection.php http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.construct.php

Comment: Also, what if I need to fetch the whole row as an object, not just the result_id?

Comment: "EOD" stands for "End Of Data" (but you could use anything). If you haven't seen it before, this is called the [heredoc syntax](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Here_document#PHP).

Comment: `PDOStatement` has quite a few fetch styles: [fetch](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php) (with a `$fetch_style` option), [fetchColumn](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchcolumn.php), [fetchObject](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchcolumn.php), [fetchAll](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php) (also with a `$fetch_style` option).